# How to mount file with specific usergroup

Tags: docker, file-permissions, user-permissions

I'm using filebeat to monitor my files via a docker container. I have some log files with the `adm` usergroup added to them with the permission `640`.

Example

```
$ echo Hello > log.txt
$ chown root:adm log.txt
$ chmod 640 log.txt
$ usermod -a -G adm filebeat
$ docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd)/log.txt:/log.txt docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:6.4.0 cat /log.txt
cat: /log.txt: Permission denied
```

the filebeat container is running from the filebeat user, shouldn't it have the same groups added to it as it has on the docker host? If not what setup should I use to be able to read from this log file within the container?